# Is there any way to use microphone in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension where i need to access microphone so that i can take voice input from user for some tasks. Is there any way to implement this.

I tried **audioCapture** permission but it is available in packed apps only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are standards in the works to get user audio / video, but they're a bit in flux and not supported across the board.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

See what I mean? But yeah, if you're only targeting Chrome, I guess you don't mind that it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I am asking about chrome extensions, not for a website

Comment: getUserMedia is what you would use if you had permission, the js API is the same if you are making an extension or making a website. Sorry, I misunderstood and didn't realise it was purely a permissions issue.

Comment: `getUserMedia` is usable in Chrome Extensions. The only trouble is to get the user's permission (once). It has to be in a visible, normal tab with a page from your extension. If you open a tab with `chrome-extension://` URL and request permission from there, it will work (and you can later use it from other contexts)